# common loader for all widgets on dashboard using loader service in angular

Tags: angular, angular7

Hi I want to create one dashboard with 4 widget in it showing loader for each widget. Each widget would be a separate component loaded in dashboard, I want to separate loader for each widget while loading data. Is it possible using single loader component and creating loader service?

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is you can create a loader component and add the selector any other component you need. You can make a service too and use it to your component

Comment: is there any example, so that I can refer it maybe on stackblitz or jsfiddle

Comment: https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/show-loader-on-every-request-in-angular-2-9a0fca86afef please read it out. you will get an idea